# The applet has requested access to the printer. Frozen

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I have an applet in a webpage that accesses printers. Sometimes I get the warning dialog in the image below and before I can click anything, the dialog freezes and causes IE to become unresponsive. Any idea what could be causing this?

[DIALOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCXL2.png)

Comment: Question ... why are you using Java Applets ?? Soon they're going to be history and I'd suggest using alternate technologies ... Oracle is planning to deprecate Applets, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/migratingfromapplets-2872444.pdf  .... read the "Executive Overview"

Comment: @Addy this is part of a big and old application that relies on applets replacing applets would take 100s of man hours. so I'm only looking for a quick fix

Comment: Then you need to post some code please, make sure you have a try..catch block around the printer function ... and also if you see something in the Java Console (see : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)